# UITableView select and deselect row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewcell that stays highlighted after touching it. I would like to know how to remove the highlight right after it becomes visible after your touch.

So when you touch the UITableViewCell I would like it to become selected and highlighted then when the user raises their finger I would like to deselect and unhighlight the UITableViewCell.

This is what I am doing so far,  and the deselect works but the cell is still highlighted.

```
#pragma mark -- select row
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text);

}

#pragma mark -- deselect row
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: ohh.. whoops. I see it now too lol

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

That's an infinite loop, I'm quite certain.  However... it's sort of on the right track.  You can move that method call into `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //stuff
    //as last line:
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

For that matter, `deselectRowAtIndexPath` can be called from anywhere at any time you want the row to be deselected.

```
[self.myTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.myTableView 
    indexPathForSelectedRow] animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to deselect row on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method**

### Example code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```